# Is there any shortcut for dragging excel cell?

Tags: excel

While using Ctrl D can fill the selected cell, is there any shortcut to fill the selected cell with a pattern, like 
1,2,3,4,5, instead of 1, 1, 1, 1, 1?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> then <kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Got this from [here](https://superuser.com/a/270272/599178).

***EDIT :*** Based on the image added in question.

For the data as shown in the image you have to select `Series Type` as `Autofill` by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: so, first I need to highlight the cell I want to drag and apply ALT HFIS Enter?

Comment: It seems that I still need to click the autofil button.

Comment: @JOHN - Right, select the cells using `Shift` and down arrow.

Comment: @JOHN - `Series Type` as `Linear` should also work. No need to select `AutoFill`.

Comment: Please check the update post. It is not working when I choose linear

Comment: @JOHN - Yup, above solution would have worked for sample data `1,2,3,4,5` provided by you. If you want this to work for the sample data in image then you can press `Alt`+`F` before pressing `Enter`.

Answer (score 0):

1)

- In Cell `A1`, enter `1`
- In Cell `A2`, enter `2`

Select both the cells and drag it down to fill for the range.

2)

Or use Fill -> Series and give the stop and step value.

Comment: Is there any keyboard shortcut to do the drag?

Comment: May be you should go with @Mrig 's answer, but both are the same function